# ssl error when returning to site after paypal payment completion

Tags: ssl, https, paypal

i have a site where users make payment throught paypal 
i am using the buy now button

after payment in paypal, the users are redirected back to the site

before redirection to site they get a warning, the one you get for https connections, whether to continue over the unsecure connection or stop

my site does not have an ssl certificate

Answer (score 1):

Sounds normal to me. If you don't want to spend the money to buy a certificate, then perhaps a paragraph about "Please note we care about your privacy; all private details are transmitted while protected with TLS. You may be alerted when leaving Paypal that you are no longer using a TLS session -- this is normal. Just don't give away private data when TLS is disabled."

Granted, no one reads anything, but that goes for the warning dialogs too.